# Using slash for template of html in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var a = 1.10;
var html = '<div>'\
  '<strong>' + a +
  '</strong>\ //error here
  </div>';

console.log(html)
```

What is wrong with the above code? I am trying to add a variable value into html.

Comment: use `+` instead of  ` \ `

Comment: please use this in one line

Comment: In case of templating, it is better to use multilines. @shivachauhan

Comment: then we have to use like this "test \ test"

Answer (score 0):

You to use it like following :

```
var html = '<div><strong>'+ a +'</strong></div>';
//OR
var html = '<div>'
    +'<strong>'+ a +'</strong>'
    +'</div>';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you heard of Escaping EOL in JavaScript? This would be useful in the case of templating and the OP is doing a template.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use:

```
var html = '<div><strong>' + a + '</strong></div>';
```

You shouldn't escape EOL until the JavaScript is ES5. But even for that, what you need is:

```
var html = '<div><strong>\
           '+ a +'\
            </strong></div>';
```

You can only escape EoL inside a string value and not outside it.

**Console**

```
> a = "hi"
< "hi"
> var html = '<div><strong>\
           '+ a +'\
            </strong></div>';
< undefined
> html
< "<div><strong>           hi            </strong></div>"
```